# SQL join over a M:N table

Tags: sql, join

there are five existing tables:

```
(MAIL)
id  senderFK  receiverFK  text
```

The senders and receivers are referenced in the `MN` table:

```
(MN)
id  studentFK  teacherFK  guestFK
```

Every entry in `MN` can only have filled `id` and one of the three foreign key columns.
If one row, for example, has `id` 42 and 16 in `studentFK`, it referes to the entry with with `id` 16 in the following table:

```
(STUD)
id  name  grade  hasStudCard
```

The other two possible tables for senders/receivers are:

```
(TEACH)
id  name  age  telephone
```

and

```
(GUEST)
id  department
```

---

Students, teachers and guest can be sender or receiver of a mail.

Now I want to create a view that fills the mail table with all data the senders and receivers can have. Of course I could make a full outer join on `Mail`, `MN` and the three others on the ids. But is there an more efficient way to do it?

Comment: are you able to modify the table structure?  This structure is kludgy and isn't in 3NF imo.

Comment: It's just an abstraction for a more complicated table structure, so it depends... :) What form are you thinking of?

Comment: So is this existing structure, or are you still thinking about it?

Comment: It's already existing. I'm using Firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
      m.id              as MailID
    , m.text            as MailText

    , snd.PersonType    as SenderType
    , snd.PersonID      as SenderID
    , snd.Name          as SenderName
    , snd.grade         as SenderGrade
    , snd.hasStudCard   as SenderHasStudCard
    , snd.age           as SenderAge
    , snd.telephone     as SenderTelephone
    , snd.department    as SenderDepartment

    , rec.PersonType    as ReceiverType
    , rec.PersonID      as ReceiverID
    , rec.Name          as ReceiverName
    , rec.grade         as ReceiverGrade
    , rec.hasStudCard   as ReceiverHasStudCard
    , rec.age           as ReceiverAge
    , rec.telephone     as ReceiverTelephone
    , rec.department    as ReceiverDepartment

from MAIL as m
join
(
    select
          p.id
        , case 
             when s.id is not null then 'Student'
             when t.id is not null then 'Teacher'
             when g.id is not null then 'Guest'
          end        as PersonType
        , coalesce(s.id, t.id, g.ID)   as PersonID
        , coalesce(s.Name, t.name, '') as Name
        , grade
        , hasStudCard
        , age
        , telephone
        , department
    from MN           as p
    left join STUDENT as s on (s.id = p.studentFK and p.teacherFK is null and p.guestFK   is null)
    left join TEACH   as t on (t.id = p.teacherFK and p.studentFK is null and p.guestFK   is null)
    left join GUEST   as g on (g.id = p.guestFK   and p.studentFK is null and p.teacherFK is null)
) as snd on snd.id = m.senderFK
join
(
    select
          p.id
        , case 
             when s.id is not null then 'Student'
             when t.id is not null then 'Teacher'
             when g.id is not null then 'Guest'
          end        as PersonType
        , coalesce(s.id, t.id, g.ID)   as PersonID
        , coalesce(s.Name, t.name, '') as Name
        , grade
        , hasStudCard
        , age
        , telephone
        , department
    from MN           as p
    left join STUDENT as s on (s.id = p.studentFK and p.teacherFK is null and p.guestFK   is null)
    left join TEACH   as t on (t.id = p.teacherFK and p.studentFK is null and p.guestFK   is null)
    left join GUEST   as g on (g.id = p.guestFK   and p.studentFK is null and p.teacherFK is null)
) as rec on rec.id = m.receiverFK
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can your RDBMS use 'WITH' clause?

```
with
mnView as (
select
  id mnId,
  CASE
    WHEN MN.studentFK IS NOT NULL THEN 'S'
    WHEN MN.teacherFK IS NOT NULL THEN 'T'
    WHEN MN.guestFK IS NOT NULL THEN 'G'
    ELSE NULL
  END mnType,
  CASE
    WHEN MN.studentFK IS NOT NULL THEN MN.studentFK
    WHEN MN.teacherFK IS NOT NULL THEN MN.teacherFK
    WHEN MN.guestFK IS NOT NULL THEN MN.guestFK
    ELSE NULL
  END refId
  from MN
),
mnDetailView as (
select mnId, mnType, STUD.name, STUD.grade, STUD.hasStudCard,
  NULL age, NULL telephone, NULL department
from mnView
  join STUD on STUD.id = mnView.refId
where mnView.mnType = 'S'
union all
select mnId, mnType, TEACH.name, NULL grade, NULL hasStudCard,
  TEACH.age, TEACH.telephone, NULL department
from mnView
  join TEACH on TEACH.id = mnView.refId
where mnView.mnType = 'T'
union all
select mnId, mnType, NULL name, NULL grade, NULL hasStudCard, 
  NULL age, NULL telephone, GUEST.department
from mnView
  join GUEST on GUEST.id = mnView.refId
where mnView.mnType = 'G'
)
select
  MAIL.id,
  MAIL.text,
  sender.mnId senderMnId, sender.mnType senderMnType, sender.name senderName,
  /* sender.grade senderGrade, ... and so on */
  receiver.mnId receiverMnId, receiver.mnType receiverMnType, receiver.name
  /* receiver.grade receiverGrade, ... and so on */
receiverName
from MAIL
  join mnDetailView sender on sender.mnId = MAIL.senderFK
  join mnDetailView receiver on receiver.mnId = MAIL.receiverFK
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite uncomfortable because the structure of tables (STUD) (TEACH) and (GUEST) is different. You can try this 'barbarian' full outer join:

```
SELECT (MAIL).id, (MAIL).text, (STUD).id, (STUD).name, (STUD).grade, (STUD).hasStudCard, (TEACH).id, (TEACH).name, (TEACH).age, (TEACH).telephone, (GUEST).id, (GUEST).department FROM (MAIL), (MN), (STUD), (TEACH), (GUEST) WHERE (MAIL).senderFK = (MN).id AND ((MN).studentFK = (STUD).id OR (MN).teacherFK = (TEACH).id OR (MN).guestFK = (GUEST).id)
```

to extract senders data and a similar one for the receivers.

In general, if one of these tables is much bigger than the others, reducing its size and performing the join on the reduced table will improve the performance.